# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger cannot be cast to org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2

We have log4j2 implementation (2.0-beta9) and also using slf4j.version 1.7.3. I am initializing the logger like

```
private transient final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

Whenever there is any error I am printing errors like

```
logger.error("Error message is : " + e); ---> This line is throwing error like
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger cannot be cast to org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Your dependencies are broken, and slf4j chooses a NOP logger.  Do you have the correct log4j2->slf4j bridge installed?

Comment: This is not working only in this class on one server, in all other places it's always worked. Here are the dependencies which we are using:      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>   and             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>

Comment: You most likely have multiple slf4j jars in your complete configuration, and classes defined by one classloader cannot be cast to classes defined in another classloader.

Comment: You are right, there were multiple slf4j jars and that's why it did not worked. Problem resolved.

Comment: What did you do to resolve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have multiple slf4j jars in your complete configuration, and classes defined by one classloader cannot be cast to classes or interfaces defined in another classloader.

Comment: What would I need to do to ignore a sl4fj jar that is being pulled in from a different repository?

Comment: @jodi Open a new question with full details.

Answer (score 0):

Also, beta9 is very old.  Please upgrade to rc2 when you have a chance.